# toggleClass showing navigation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out all day how can I apply the transition effect which is on " #menu-icon .navigation" in @media query to my mobile navigation when #menu-icon is clicked to toggleClass('active') and to show the .navigation class  ( and ofc my navigation to the screen with this transition  effect )  Any ideas where is my mistake ?

```js
(function(){
 'use strict';

 $(document).ready(function(){
  var $toggleMenu = $('#menu-icon');
  
  $toggleMenu.on('click', function(){
   $('.navigation').toggleClass('active');
  });
 });

})();
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.navigation ul { list-style: none; margin-left: 5px; }
.navigation ul li { display: inline-block; margin: 0 29px 0 0; }
.navigation ul li a { display: block; padding: 6px 0 8px 0; text-decoration: none; font-size: 15px; color: #e7d9bb; }
.navigation ul li a:hover { color: #a4987f; }

/* Mobile nav icon */ 
#menu-icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 12px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#menu-icon span,
#menu-icon span:before,
#menu-icon span:after { position: absolute; left: 0; height: 3px; background: #fff; width: 100%; border-radius: 2px; }
#menu-icon span:before { content: ''; top: 10px; }
#menu-icon span:after { content: ''; top: -10px; }

@media (max-width: 480) {
  .navigation { display: none; background: #5a9abe; position: absolute; top: 100%; width: 100%; max-width: 300px; padding: 0px 0 25px 0; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }
  #menu-icon .navigation { transition: opacity .3s ease, visibility 0s linear .3s; }
  #menu-icon .navigation { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; transition: opacity .3s ease, visibility 0s linear 0s; }
  #menu-icon { display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 85%; z-index: 999999; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-nav">
  <a id="menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
  <nav class="navigation active">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">New Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- navigation -->
</div><!-- main-nav -->
```

Comment: For starters, there doesn't seem to be any styles set in your CSS for the `.active` class ?

Comment: I want to use this transition effect for my .active class and when .active class is added, I want my .navigation to be displayed on the mobile screen .

Comment: Also `#menu-icon .navigation`is searching for navigation inside the menu-icon but they are **siblings**

Comment: Also `@media (max-width: 480)` needs units

Comment: @media (max-width: 480px)

Comment: Thank you I realized my mistake .

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `active` class within the actual HTML and modify your CSS to the following:

```
body {
    background: #000;
}

.navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.navigation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 29px 0 0;
}

.navigation ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 0 8px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #e7d9bb;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
    color: #a4987f;
}
/* Mobile nav icon */

#menu-icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 12px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
}

#menu-icon span,
#menu-icon span:before,
#menu-icon span:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: white;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    z-index: 100;
}

#menu-icon span:before {
    content: '';
    top: 10px;
}

#menu-icon span:after {
    content: '';
    top: -10px;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {

 .active { //need to add some sort of logic for active
        display: inline-block;
        opacity: 1 !important;
        color: white;
        top: 0% !important; //on active, navigation is in the screen
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
 }

 .navigation {
    background: #5a9abe;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%; //navigation is originally hidden above the screen
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 0px 0 25px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duration: 0.5s; //make sure the transition duration is only in the media query
 }

 .navigation ul li {
    width: 100%;
 }

 #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 85%;
    z-index: 999999;
 }

}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/auaLqccv/

I didn't really go through and modify anything else. I just wanted the functionality to be there first. Style it how you see fit.